# i am getting Warning: found unsupported runtime 'nodejs18.x' for function 'rs-ms-v1' × Unsupported runtime

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework, serverless-architecture

i tried to update my application from node 16 to node 18 and after completing my changes versions i started my app and sent a api call and i received following output .

```
Warning: found unsupported runtime 'nodejs18.x' for function 'rs-ms-v1'
× Unsupported runtime
```

we are using serverless.yml file

my serverless library version is 3.33.0
i checked the aws documentation lambda functions started to support nodejs18.x

please attach your solutions below .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nodejs18.x has been supported since version [3.25.0](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/releases/tag/v3.25.0), so there are a couple things to check:

1. Inside your project directory, run `serverless --version` to ensure that you're not overriding a global installation of `serverless framework` with an older one inside the project.
2. Double check any plugins you're using to verify this error is not being returned by a plugin. It sounds like you may be running a local emulator to execute your function (like serverless-offline), which also may need to be updated.
3. Share logs from CloudWatch if this problem persists.

Comment: correct i have to update serverless-offline package

Answer (score 1):

so i found the answer so i updated the serverless library but i did not updated the serverless-offline library , due to that we are getting this error. latest serverless versions are supporting nodejs18.x .in order to use serverless please update all the packages related to serverless .

Answer (score 1):

1. Upgrade the `serverless` CLI

```
curl -o- -L https://slss.io/install | bash
# validate
sls --version
```

2. uninstall & re-install last version of `serverless-offline`

```
npm uninstall serverless-offline --save-dev
npm i serverless-offline --save-dev
```